# labels in neo4j 2.0 with spring data neo4j 3.0.0

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.1 with Spring-data-Neo4j 3.0.0 and I'm trying to use the new Label feature.

My entities are annotated with `@TypeAlias`, my repositories extend GraphRepository and RelationshipOperationsRepository.

When I perform `repository.save(entity)`, the entity is saved the old way (with `__Type__` attribute) and queries like `match (entity:EntityLabel) return entity` doesn't return anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade to Spring-data-Neo4j 3.0.1